# SQL Server merge two table records

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have two tables OLD and NEW as,

OLD table record : 
Column  A      B         C   D   E   F   G   H
    John Test | 1234567 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 3 | 1 | Scott

NEW table record :

```
John Test | 1234567 | null | null | 2 | null | null | Scott
```

Wanted to merge those rows in such a way, that outputs

```
John Test | 1234567 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 1 | Scott
```

The rule is to take old record if exists and look for a change in new record excluding null.Matching row is based on column B(ie.1234567)

Comment: Hi.  We need extra information to be able to help you.  Please read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). e.g. What is the rule for combining the two?  If the new table has a value, use that, otherwise use old?  How do we match rows between old and new?  What are the column names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both tables have the same number of records?

If yes, do this:

```
SELECT 
    ISNULL(New.A,Old.A),
    ISNULL(New.C,Old.C),
    ISNULL(New.D,Old.D),
    ISNULL(New.E,Old.E),
    ISNULL(New.F,Old.F),
    ISNULL(New.G,Old.G),
    ISNULL(New.H,Old.H),
FROM OldTable Old
INNER JOIN NewTable New
    ON Old.B = New.B
```

If not, and you want to have all records, do this:

```
SELECT 
    ISNULL(New.A,Old.A),
    ISNULL(New.C,Old.C),
    ISNULL(New.D,Old.D),
    ISNULL(New.E,Old.E),
    ISNULL(New.F,Old.F),
    ISNULL(New.G,Old.G),
    ISNULL(New.H,Old.H),
FROM OldTable Old
LEFT JOIN NewTable New
    ON Old.B = New.B

UNION ALL

SELECT 
    New.A,
    New.C,
    New.D,
    New.E,
    New.F,
    New.G,
    New.H,
FROM NewTable New
LEFT JOIN OldTable Old
    ON Old.B = New.B
WHERE
    Old.B IS NULL
```